# Can there be a torque-less net force on a dipole in a magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, torque, dipole, dipole-moment

I realise that a magnetic dipole moment is essentially defined on the basis of torque, which also seems to imply that a magnetic field imposed on a current-carrying closed loop can only induce a torque, and never a net force.

Are there any exceptions to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can there be a torque-less net force on a dipole in a magnetic field?

Yes, such as when there is a point in the field where the magnetic field is zero but its directional derivative in some direction is not zero. This is because

$$\vec\tau=\vec m\times\vec B$$

but

$$\vec F=(\vec m\cdot\vec\nabla)\vec B.$$

You can also make the torque be zero, even if the field isn’t zero anywhere, by aligning the dipole parallel or antiparallel to the field. But to get a force you have to have a nonuniform field.

> a magnetic dipole moment is essentially defined on the basis of torque

Although this is how [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment) says it “can be” defined, this definition is generally used only in introductory treatments. At a more advanced level, one can find a general multipole expansion of the magnetic vector potential for a current loop using the equations

$$\vec A(\vec r)=\frac{I}{c}\oint\frac{d\vec\ell’}{|\vec r-\vec r’|}$$

and

$$\frac{1}{|\vec r-\vec r’|}=\frac1r\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{r’}{r}\right)^nP_n(\cos\theta)$$

where $P_n(x)$ is a Legendre polynomial and $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec r$ and $\vec r’$.

See [this lecture](http://www.pas.rochester.edu/%7Edmw/phy217/Lectures/Lect_30b.pdf) for how the $n=1$ term leads to the following definition of the dipole moment for an arbitrarily-shaped current loop, simply in terms of where current is flowing in space:

$$\vec m\equiv\frac{I}{2c}\oint \vec r’\times d\vec\ell’.$$

The $n=2$ term gives the loop’s quadrupole moment and vector potential, the $n=3$ term the octupole, etc.

More general treatments might work with a current *density* in space rather than a current confined to a wire, but a multipole expansion based on powers of $1/r$ and Legendre polynomials (or spherical harmonics) would be similar.

Note: These equations are in Gaussian, not SI, units.

Comment: Thanks, but this is way out of the physics I know; did you mean it *is* possible, but in a non-uniform field?

Comment: Yes, it is possible but the field would have to be non-uniform. A uniform field exerts a torque, but no force, on a magnetic dipole.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I wanted.